# Xcode When validation app i have one error how to fix it?

Tags: ios, xcode

Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets: xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues. A

!Your account already has a valid ios Distribution certificate not installed You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center, but it is developer locally. If your signing identity is installed on another Mac, you can export a certificate. profile on that Mac and import it on this Mac. You can also reset your current Reset or Import Developer

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+Failed+to+locate+or+generate+matching+signing+assets) before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that the distribution certificate you are using i.e which is there in your key chain is not the correct one, either download the correct one from developer account and installed it to your Mac or export it from another machine where you have the valid one.